# Adding Git Commit to bash_profile with prompt?

Tags: git, unix, terminal

I want aliases for:

```
git add --a
git commit -m ""
git push origin master
git pull origin master
```

I have made them all, except how do I have terminal prompt me for a commit message, and then store it?

So:

```
commit
"What's your commit message"
added footer <enter>
git commit -m "added footer"
```

Is that possible to do?

I tried doing a `printf` and `read` variable, and then inserting that with `$variable` but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you know that if you simply do `git commit`, you'll be taken to a commit message editor? You don't need to do `git commit -m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use functions instead of aliases:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

commit(){
    echo "What's your commit message?"
    read msg
    git commit -m "$msg"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it via a function instead of a single alias:

```
commit () {
    echo "What's your commit message?"
    read a
    git commit -m $a
}
```

Though, even in this case, you won't be able to have commits longer than a line. If you want more than that (and it is recommended that you do this), you should open an editor with a temporary file and use that.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I personally use in my .bash_profile:

```
commit(){
  git commit -m "$*"
}
alias gc=commit
```

Simple and sweet.

```
$ gc This is a really long commit message
```